# Undefined property: stdClass::$salarie

Tags: php, laravel

I have two table SALARIES and POINTAGES And between them a relationship hasMany belongsTo, I want to display for each POINTAGE a SALARIES corresponds but it gives me this error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$salarie

`consulter.blade.php`

```
@foreach($pointages as $pointage)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $pointage->datep }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->chantier }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->ouvrage }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->nbrj }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->solde }}</td>
  <td>{{ $pointage->salarie->nom }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

`Pointage.php`

```
 protected $fillable = [
  'salarie_id', 'datep', 'solde', 'nbrj' , 'ouvrage' , 'chantier' , 'prime' ,
];
 public function salarie(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Salarie');
 }
```

`Salarie.php`

```
public function pointages(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Pointage');
}
```

`pointages` migration:

```
public function up(){
  Schema::table('pointages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('salarie_id')->unsigned()->after('id');
    $table->foreign('salarie_id')->references('id')->on('salaries');  
  });
}
```

`SalarieController.php`

```
public function consulter(){
  $salaries = Salarie::with('pointages')->get();
  $pointages = DB::table('pointages')->get();
  return view('salarie.consulter', compact('salaries','pointages'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a relationship, like `public function salarie()` on your `Pointage` model, you need to actually query it. Don't use `DB::table()`, use `Pointage`:

```
$pointages = Pointages::get();
```

Also, to avoid additional queries when looping `$pointages`, eager load your relationship:

```
$pointages = Pointages::with(["salarie"])->get();
```

In summary, `DB::table()` **does not** return a `Pointage` model, so you can't use `->salarie`. Use your model.

Edit: There is a chance that a `Pointage` doesn't have a `Salarie` associated, so you need to handle that. Either enforce the relationship with a `->has()` query, or check while looping:

```
$pointages = Pointages::with(["salarie"])->has("salarie")->get();
```

Or, in your view:

```
@if($pointages->salarie)
<td>{{ $pointage->salarie->nom }}</td>
@else
<td>No Salarie...</td>
@endif
```

Comment: I write like that $pointages = Pointage::get(); but it gives me error Trying to get property 'nom' of non-object

Comment: That means that `$pointage->salarie` is returning `null`. You need to handle all possibilities... I'll make an update for that.

Comment: i write like that $pointages = Pointage::with(["salarie"])->has("salarie")->get();, it does not display any error, but it return datatable empty

Comment: That means that your query is returning 0 `Pointage` items as there are none in the database that have a `salarie`. Did you define your relationship right?

Comment: i think my relationship is correct ,you can check it

Comment: If you think the relationship is correct, check the records in your database. Are there any records in your `pointages` table that have a `salarie_id` that matches a record in the `salaries` table? If there are, then your relationship is *not* correct.